# how to replace string in javascript using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

there is a string and RegExp:

```
var str = "a1c a23c a456c 123";
var re = /a(\d*)c/g;
```

I want to match all **number** between `a` and `c`, and replace it to `b`, the result I would like is:

```
"abc abc abc 123"
```

how to do it?

Comment: Your regex would also match `"ac"` with no number - is that deliberate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
    var str = "a1c a23c a456c 123";
    var re = /(a)(\d*)(c)/g;
    
    console.log(str.replace(re, '$1b$3'));
```

**EDIT:**

If `ac` should not become `abc`, then regex should be `/(a)(\d+)(c)/g`

Comment: This would also replace "ac" with "abc".

Comment: If we don't want to, then regex should be `/(a)(\d+)(c)/g`

Comment: No need of capturing group as both characters are static.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var str = "a1c a23c a456c 123";
var newStr = str.replace(/\ba\d+c\b/g, "abc");
console.log(newStr);
```

Comment: No need of capturing group `/\ba\d+c\b/g, 'abc'`.